# How to make AsyncLocal flow to siblings?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

This is a very simple example I expect to work but...

```
    static AsyncLocal<bool> _value = new AsyncLocal<bool>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A().Wait();
    }

    static async Task A()
    {
        await B();
        await C();
    }

    static async Task B()
    {
        _value.Value = true;
    }

    static async Task C()
    {
        if (!_value.Value) throw new Exception();
    }
```

So is there a possibility to store something inside method `B` in a way so that a value is available in `C`? I need it to be passed only through async flow (no `ThreadStatic` please).

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why static is not an option?

Comment: @Carl in a real-world app the value is kept on an instance field and should be separate for different async flows coming in.

Comment: `await C(await B());`? since C will not do any work until B has returned anyway.

Comment: What exactly would you expect the code as stated to do? You have a race condition there. If `B` manages to race through its code before `C` gets a chance to run, then `_value.Value` will be true, otherwise it will be false. It seems that `C` will be pretty random.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen C won't be called before B finishes because B is awaited.

Comment: You're right, missed that.

Comment: @Carl it won't affect the problem. Try it yourself with adding a return value and a parameter.

Comment: Why aren't you simply either passing a common object into B() which B modifies and then pass it into C, or why aren't you simply returning a value from B and pass that value into C?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen because it's a simplified example to illustrate the problem. In a real app more things are involved. You are not passing `Monitor` to all called methods just to make reentrance work, right?

Comment: Well, *I* am, probably because I'm not a big fan of ambient "magical" state. I'm a much much bigger fan of explicit passing in what each class and method should have access to.

Comment: There is clearly something to the question you have not revealed. You are talking about this app of your, "draw picture" for us, since, 'await C(await B());' is completely suited as and answer for the question you have asked just beneath the code. Invest in your questions, then we might invest into answering it.

Comment: @Carl ok, anyway I already answered it myself, pls look if you are interested

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So this is what I discovered:

- `AsyncLocal` are only transfered one way - from outer-level to inner-level async methods so I added a `B_Start` method which initializes the local at a "top" level.
- Changes inside an inner method are not transferred back even for already initialized locals but you can mutate fields on a reference-type container.

Working code:

```
    class Container<T>
    {
        public T Value { get; set; }
    }
    static AsyncLocal<Container<bool>> _value = new AsyncLocal<Container<bool>>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A().Wait();
    }

    static async Task A()
    {
        await B_Start();
        await C();
    }

    static Task B_Start()
    {
        _value.Value = new Container<bool>();
        return B();
    }

    static async Task B()
    {
        _value.Value.Value = true;
    }

    static async Task C()
    {
        if (!_value.Value.Value) throw new Exception();
    }
```

Comment: `but you can mutate fields on a reference-type container` - no, you should never do this. Nothing will stop you, but you will end up in a world of pain.

Comment: @StephenCleary please provide a real argument for that. I'm already using this and it just works.

Comment: @Vlad: Consider fork/join scenarios, such as Task.WhenAll.

Comment: @StephenCleary, is fork/join documented for AsyncLocal? I assume that WhenAll task is considered an outer scope so any child AsyncLocal state will be lost. Anyway I'm going to use such storage in `using` statement where only the most outer task sets the value. I needed a ref container for my disposable to be able to correctly reset state even if it's disposed somehow from another task which doesn't have this local state.

Comment: @StephenCleary  And also I need a container because I want the state to be available in the same outer-level task but to set the actual value after some internal await in the same method so I use `B_Start` technique. No fork/join there.

Comment: @Vlad: Here's a blog post that goes into more detail on [how it's broken unless used with immutable types](http://blog.i3arnon.com/2015/05/16/logicaloperationstack-async-bug/).

Comment: @Vlad Did you get any problems with your solution? I built today almost the same before I saw this question. I have the requirement that during deeping down to other tasks that every task can add a message to a collection. At the end on the outer task I will readout all this messages. Do you think your solution is also the right approach for my problem?

Comment: @Tester I'm not sure to answer whether it's the right approach for you but in my case it works well.

Comment: The mutable "wrap" ref type works fine for 99.9% cases. The ambient call context is needed despite what purists say. For example, you may not pass a parameter for `XService` into all methods if you don't know what `XService` is when you write such methods. Or maybe those are 3rd party libraries that have set signatures. How do you pass cross-cutting things like principal, session, culture, call flow and other contexts without an ambient design pattern?  Here is what I use simialr to what @Vlad did https://github.com/azist/azos/blob/master/src/Azos/Platform/AsyncFlowMutableLocal.cs